# I tried to delete some items from the SQL database but I got an integrity constraint error

Tags: oracle

I tried the following query to delete some rows from the SQL database but it's showing following error:

**Query:**

```
Delete From Document_Type where Doc_Type_id='case'
```

**This is the error:**

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
delete From Document_Type where Doc_Type_Desc='Case'


Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (NW_DEV_281015.FK_COMMENTS_DOCUMENT_TYPE6) violated - child record found
02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"

*Cause:    attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign dependency.

*Action:   delete dependencies first then parent or disable constraint.
```

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I assume Oracle by the error.

Like the error message said, you have a constraint that forces the child table to be connected. So first, delete the same records from the child table:

```
DELETE FROM Child_Table t
WHERE t.<FK> IN(SELECT s.PK FROM Document_Type s where s.Doc_Type_Desc='Case')
```

Then do you delete. Or alternativly , disable the constraint :

```
alter table
   table_name
DISABLE constraint
   constraint_name;
```